# How can i turn off or on post processing for all scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made a checkbox in my title screen but I can't figure out how to enable or disable post-processing in all scenes with it. I'm using Unity 2020.1 and I have it [linked to my code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDOBl.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few routes you could take with this.

1. You could take the post processing volume(s) that you wish to disable as a parameter into your script, and [disable/enable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) them like any other component.
2. You could put the post processing volume(s) on their own GameObject(s) and [disable/enable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) the GameObjects.
3. I believe in at least URP, you can enable/disable post processing all together through rendering options of the camera you are using. Not 100% sure on this one though, but worth may be looking into.

Comment: The n1 option does not work for Post Process component.

Comment: The n 2 option also is not true. In Unity 2020 if you make a game object and you add a Post Process it will require a camera that will pop up in the hierarchy. And if you move the PP it will also create a camera.